# Uncaught reference error; function is defined yet coming undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the javascript function that I wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rate_prof(opcode, prof_id) {
    $.ajax({
        alert('Got an error dude');
        type: "POST",
            url: "/caller/",
            data: {
                mnemonics: opcode,
                prof_id: prof_id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                /*if(data!=="False"){
                    tempBool = false;
                    alert(data);
                    location.reload();
                }*/
            },
            failure: function(data) {
                alert('Got an error dude');
            },
            dataType: "html"
    });
}
</script>
```

Now on calling this function by a button this way-

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" value = "LIKE" onclick="rate_prof('LIKE',{{prof_rate.get_prof.get_username}})">Like</button>
```

I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: rate_prof is not defined" in inspect element console.

One - the function is correctly defined and two - the source code of the page also shows this function. So what might be the problem?

I have not defined functionality inside, but that can be done easily after that button calls the function. I am new in javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry language problem, when I see in inspect element console, I get this error- Uncaught ReferenceError: rate_prof is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the alert from the argument here:

```
$.ajax({
   alert('Got an error dude'); // This line doesn't define an object property
   type: "POST",
   url: "/caller/",
          :
});
```

A syntax error due to `alert` breaks your code, and the function will never be defined.