# ajax not called..even alerts are not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am writing this code in my html page to hide one id in that page..alerts are also not working..method is not called

```
*<script>    
alert("yo");    
$(function checkUsertype(email_id)
    {    
    alert("yup")   
    var usertype   = $("#txtusertype").val();    
    $.ajax({    
        alert("hide")    
        url: 'rest/search/userType?email_id='+email_id,    
        type : "GET",
        datatype : 'json',
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) 
           {
               if(usertype=='webuser')
               {
               $("#themer").hide();
               }
                },
               error : function(xhr, data, statusText,errorThrown) 
               {
           }
           });
})
alert("yo");
<script/>*
```

Comment: What is `*`? Are these copy-paste error?

Comment: yes..while pasting in stack

Comment: [A dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30442686/1169519)?

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem.

```
$.ajax({    
    alert("hide")
```

You're trying to `alert` inside the `ajax` which is **Syntax error**. Try removing the `alert` inside `ajax` and it should work.

You can use `alert` in `success`, `error` callbacks as follow:

```
$(function checkUsertype(email_id) {
    var usertype = $("#txtusertype").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'rest/search/userType?email_id=' + email_id,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('In Success'); // Use it here
            console.log(data); // Log the response
            if (usertype == 'webuser') {
                $("#themer").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, data, statusText, errorThrown) {
            alert('In Error'); // Use it here
            console.log(errorThrown); // Log the error
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes...after removing it first alert is working but second alert is not working

Comment: compiler is not entering into method

Comment: console.log (  inside this what i have to give? )

Comment: tanx bro..now ican see something in console

Comment: im getting this errorr: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Comment: @user3504024 That means jquery is not loaded on page or you are using it before it is loaded

Comment: @user3504024 If your problem is solved, you can accept the answer